# define `id` function using point-free notation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pointfree

In Haskell language function `id` defined to be unit of composition:

```
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

Is there a way to define haskell' `id` function using point-free notation?
I mean not to directly referencing it like:

```
same :: a -> a
same = id
```

Comment: There are many ways, `flip const undefined` or `head . return` and many others, but there's no point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The pointfree version of `id` is... well, `id`. `id` is often taken as a fundamental operator in pointfree constructions, a sort of a primitive upon which more combinators are constructed.

If you really want, you can reconstruct `id` from other more complex operators, e.g. exploiting the `Monad ((->) a)` instance:

```
id = join const
```

or the `Applicative ((->) a)` instance

```
id = const <*> const
```

(in combinatory logic, this is `I = S K K` since `<*>` is `S` and `const` is `K`)

Nothing can be simpler than `id` itself, though.

Answer (score 4):

This question is an interesting one, because `id` is essentially the identity of any mathematical group of functions under composition. To put it simply, when you get two opposite functions and  compose them, you get `id`.

So, any of these will work polymorphically and in the same way, though naturally slower:

```
id :: a -> a
----------------------------
id = snd . (0,)
id = fst . (,0)
id = (!! 0) . return
id = ($ 0) . const
id = (\(Just n) -> n) . Just
```

Or, we could write it in a simple lambda expression, which is good practice and very simple:

```
id = \a -> a
```

All of these are in points-free style, which should be satisfactory for your question, but it's not just points-free, but quite point-less. All these solutions may seem very valid, and they are, but they're *not* equivalent to `id`. These solutions, not including the last one, build and deconstruct datastructures which are expensive in performance. Points-free style may be good practice, but not everywhere.